# What are build-dependencies?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

"Build dependencies" explained in the [cargo book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#build-dependencies):

> You can depend on other Cargo-based crates for use in your build scripts. Dependencies are declared through the `build-dependencies` section of the manifest

I have difficulty in understanding what exactly this means and what's the difference between the normal `dependencies` and `build-dependencies`.

Answer (score 4):

They're a bit different:

`dependencies`: You can use them under `src` directory (which is normally you write your source code for the main program)

`build-dependencies`: You can use them only in `build.rs` on project root, which is used to prepare some external dependencies or invoke external command before the program being built (and is called "build script")

Comment: what is the source?